# Go syscall EnumProcessModules

Tags: go, system-calls

Im trying to call ;EnumProcessModules; using Go of a given handle

```
var (
    psapi = syscall.NewLazyDLL("Psapi.dll")
    procEnumProcessModules = psapi.NewProc("EnumProcessModules")
)

func EnumProcessModules(handle uintptr) {
    log.Println(handle)
    modules := make([]interface{}, 2049)
    var needed int
    procEnumProcessModules.Call(
        handle,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&modules)),
        uintptr(2048),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&needed)),
    )
    log.Println(needed)
    for i := 0; i < needed; i++ {
        log.Println(modules[i])
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work... needed is set but the moment I try to access modules variable I get the following error:

```
unexpected fault address 0x12d0000
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x12d0000 pc=0x455b56]
```

How should the modules array look like?

Comment: According to EnumProcessModules documentation, the modules is an array of handles. So it should be modules := make(syscall.Handle, 2049). And last parameter of EnumProcessModules is *uint32, so your "needed" variable should be uint32, not int. int does not have fixed size (it is int32 on 386, and is int64 on amd64).

Comment: You're passing a slice pointer to a windows function that knows nothing about slices. You wither need to use an array or use the address of the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must reference the first element.

```
var n uint32
var needed uint32

// How many I need?
ret, _, _ := procEnumProcessModules.Call(
  uintptr(handle),
  0,
  uintptr(n),
  uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&needed)))

if int(ret) == 1 && needed > 0 {

  procHandles := make([]syscall.Handle, needed) 
  procHandlesPtr := unsafe.Pointer(&procHandles[0])

  n = needed
  ret2, _, _ := procEnumProcessModules.Call(
    uintptr(n),
    uintptr(procHandlesPtr),
    uintptr(n), 
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&needed))))

  if int(ret2) == 1 {
    for i:= 0; i < needed / 4; i++ {
       fmt.Println(procHandles[i])
  }
}
```